# Rails uploading Rails app to Passenger server

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, deployment, java-web-start

I've uploaded my Rails app from a svn repository to my server. In my localhost it works ok, but when I try to access by Chrome I get the following error:

```
There appears to be a database problem.
Your config/database.yml may not be written correctly. Please check it and fix any errors.
Your database schema may be out of date or nonexistant. Please run rake db:migrate to ensure that the database schema is up-to-date.
The database server may not be running. Please check whether it's running, and start it if it isn't.
```

I've no idea what to do, because it's the first time I try to upload a rails project and I'm doing the same things I do in localhost in remote server.

By the way, should I run rails s too throught the ssh connection?

Comment: Checkout Capistrano and Deprec.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean.
I forgot this error:
`database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)`

Comment: BTW - what is the connection to [tag:webstart]?

Answer (score 1):

Update: first thing to do is get educated on deploying: [start here on the Rails site](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy).

So the thing is, on your server you need to have a database set up, like you do on your local machine.  Checking out the code from SVN only gets you the application, not the database.

You mention in the title that you have Passenger set up on the server.  Passenger is a module of Apache (or Nginx) which replace the `rails s` command you are using in development.  It is in this passenger configuration file that you'll need to set the `RailsEnv <something>` to determine what and how the app starts and runs.

If the database servers are the same (e.g. MySQL on both platforms) and the environments are the same (e.g. "development"), and if the `app/db/database.yml` file is checked into source control, then skip ahead.

If your database and environment is different (e.g. SQLLite in development and MySQL in production) then you'll need to add the necessary configuration -- database name, host, port, usename, password for the environment in the database.yml (and specify the proper database gem in your Gemfile, based on the environment).  If you are storing passwords, I don't recommend checking in the database.yml file, but that's a separate topic.  In the end, you need to have the right database config in database.yml on the server.

Then, you can run `bundle exec rake db:setup` on the server from your app's root directory.  This will initialize the database with the current schema, and run any seeds.rb setup needed.  Check with `rake -T` to see other options you might consider.

Once that's done, subsequent deployments require that you check out your latest code from SVN, and usually restart the app (with Passenger, this is done with the command `touch tmp/restart.txt` from the app's root directory.  If you have made changes to the database structure, before restarting, run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Oh, yeah, in production, if you're using the default environment, you'll also need to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` the first time, and every time afterwards if you have added images, changed javascript/coffeescript or css/sass files.

Having said this, @rwilliams comment about Capistrano is definitely something you'll want to think about.  Deploying is tricky as you can see, and as your app gets bigger you'll want it to be simple.  Capistrano allows you to set up a script of things that make deployment a command like `cap deploy` or `cap staging deploy:migrations`.  It's a lot to learn, but worth the effort.